# ruby, kernel module methods documentation

Tags: ruby, module

This thing in the documentation of the [Ruby Kernel module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html) confuses me.

As far as i've understood, the Kernel module is included by the class Object. 
Doing so makes all its instance methods as they were Object's methods, and so, any other class's methods. 
So far so good; then the doc states that:

```
The Kernel instance methods are documented in class Object while the module methods are documented here
```

Ok. But then again, all the methods fall under the section:

```
Public Instance Methods
```

Methods like `sprintf`, `lambda`, `load`, `loop` seem to me to be clearly class-like methods, not instance methods, even if they are "called without receiver". 
But that can't be correct because there's a certain consistence in presenting them as instance methods; on the left Methods Box they are called with the 'instance method convention', that is #some_method.
So why is this? Are they instance or what else? And if they're instance methods, which instance are they related to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Object` itself is an object. When `Kernel` is included in Object, its instance methods become instance methods of `Object`, but also instance methods of the object `Object`(a.k.a class methods of Object). Yes, that means that the object `Object` has `Object` in its class' ancestor chain.

`Object.class.ancestors` # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Comment: So you are saying that instead of calling these methods 'class methods', they are calling them instance methods of the class's class object?

Comment: Exactly! When you want to define a "class method", you have to do something like `def self.foo`, which is actually adding a the method `foo` to the instance `self`.

Comment: But where does it say so in the documentation? They seem to be just regular instance mehtods, not instance methods of the 'self' class, aren't they?

Comment: Instance methods are the only methods Ruby has. Way may *talk* about class methods, but those are really just instance methods of the class `Class` of which all classes are instances. Or they are singleton methods of the class. But actually, there aren't singleton methods either, they are just regular instance methods of the object's singleton class. So, when we say "class methods", we actually either mean "instance methods of `Class` or any of its superclasses (`Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, `BasicObject`) or we mean "instance methods of the class's singleton class".

Comment: ok. thank you for the clarification. and how does this apply to the Kernel module? Including it into the object class makes its methods instance methods of Object, not instance methods of Object's class, so Object class methods, doesn't it?